# Multistep form with dynamic data

Tags: drupal

I am creating a website where I want to have a list of categories on the first page, on selecting a category, it would take you to a list of sub-categories. And on selecting a sub-category, it would take you to a questionnaire based on the particular sub-category and finally, an email is sent to the admin with the details including the category, sub-category and answers to the questionnaire. I am fairly new to Drupal, but I have experience in Joomla and in core programming in PHP/Javascript. I tried to do it using Webforms, but it seems that it cannot be used for the dynamic data, I want the sub-categories to be dynamically loaded when the category is selected and the same thing applies for the questionnaire. Please suggest me appropriate module(s) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: Form wizard in the [Chaos Tools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module. It has a great API to create multi-step forms.